# python dictionary key not working

Tags: python, defaultdict

I'm having trouble accessing some values in a dictionary I made. In my code, I made two different dictionaries while reading through a file. The code I have is this:

```
nonterminal_rules = defaultdict(list)
terminal_rules = defaultdict(list)

for line in open(file, 'r').readlines():
    LHS,RHS = line.strip().split("->")
    if RHS[1] == "'" and RHS[-1] == "'" :
        terminal_rules[LHS].append(RHS.strip())
    else:
        nonterminal_rules[LHS].append(RHS.split())

for i in nonterminal_rules:
    for j in nonterminal_rules[i]:
        if len(j) == 1:
            x = terminal_rules[j[0]])
```

Here are the keys and values to my dict:

```
print(self.original_grammar.terminal_rules.items())
dict_items([('NN ', ["'body'", "'case'", "'immunity'", "'malaria'", "'mouse'", "'pathogen'", "'research'", "'researcher'", "'response'", "'sepsis'", "'system'", "'type'", "'vaccine'"]), ('NNS ', ["'cells'", "'fragments'", "'humans'", "'infections'", "'mice'", "'Scientists'"]), ('Prep ', ["'In'", "'with'", "'in'", "'of'", "'by'"]), ('IN ', ["'that'"]), ('Adv ', ["'today'", "'online'"]), ('PRP ', ["'this'", "'them'", "'They'"]), ('Det ', ["'a'", "'A'", "'the'", "'The'"]), ('RP ', ["'down'"]), ('AuxZ ', ["'is'", "'was'"]), ('VBN ', ["'alerted'", "'compromised'", "'made'"]), ('Adj ', ["'dendritic'", "'immune'", "'infected'", "'new'", "'Systemic'", "'weak'", "'whole'", "'live'"]), ('VBN  ', ["'discovered'"]), ('Aux ', ["'have'"]), ('VBD ', ["'alerted'", "'injected'", "'published'", "'rescued'", "'restored'", "'was'"]), ('COM ', ["','"]), ('PUNC ', ["'?'", "'.'"]), ('PossPro ', ["'their'", "'Their'"]), ('MD ', ["'Will'"]), ('Conj ', ["'and'"]), ('VBP ', ["'alert'", "'capture'", "'display'", "'have'", "'overstimulate'"]), ('VB  ', ["'work'"]), ('VBZ ', ["'invades'", "'is'", "'shuts'"]), ('NNP ', ["'Dr'", "'Jose'", "'Villadangos'"])])
```

Let's say I have the key-value pair {Aux:["have"]}.
The problem is, if i = Aux, for example, x is just set as an empty list, when I actually want to be equal to ["have"].

I'm not sure what I'm doing/accessing incorrectly. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: It'd be probably easier to show the output as the result of self.original_grammar.terminal_rules.items(), and you may want to show it both for terminal_rules and non_terminal_rules.  It'd be easier to look at the dictionary that way instead of having to look at key/values individually.

Comment: There are no empty lists in your output, `["','"]` is not considered an empty list.

Comment: with the key:value pair `{"Aux":["have"]}`, `i == "Aux"`, `nonterminal_rules[i] == ["have"]`, and `terminal_rules[j[0]]` is a `KeyError`, which means for a `defaultdict(list)` it creates an empty list and assigns it to `x`.

Comment: This is the classic XY problem. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @adsmith I'm not sure what an XY problem is. This is my (admittedly crude) attempt at converting a grammar to Chomsky Normal Form.The thing is, I don't know why there's would be a key error. Because for example, nonterminal[i] will produce a list, and if the list is ["Aux"], I can look into my variables window in my IDE and see that ["Aux"] exists as a key in terminal_rules, but I can't seem to get at it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming from reading your code that you want all things that start and end with ', correct?  In that case, you probably want

```
if RHS[0] == "'" and RHS[-1] == "'" :
    terminal_rules[LHS].append(RHS.strip())
```

Since 0 is the first character of the string :).  If ' isn't the second character of the split string, then right now it'll add everything to non_terminal_rules.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I would've figured, but when I use RHS[0] instead of RHS[1], the dictionary ends up empty and I have no idea why...

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to set `terminal_rules` to be every key:value pair in `nonterminal_rules` that is of length 1, do this:

```
nonterminal_rules = defaultdict(list)
terminal_rules = defaultdict(list)

for line in open(file, 'r').readlines():
# Do stuff here as you've done above

terminal_rules = {key:value for key,value in nonterminal_rules.items() if len(value) == 1}
```

Comment: Not quite. nonterminal_rules[i] should produce a list of lists. If this produced list is only one member long, I want to look up the first index of that list, use it as the key in terminal_rules and then save the value its associated with. I can look in my variables window and see when terminal_rules has a given key, but even when I can see that it is there, the the code seems to make a second key and return an empty list.

Comment: Here's an example. Let's say nonterminal_rules has an entry {AUX:['Aux']}, and in terminal_rules there's the entry {Aux:["is","was"]}. What I ultimately want is to create a new dictionary that will be like {AUX:["is","was"]}. I need to do this for a number of entries, through, and only when the pair in nonterminal_rules has a value that is len == 1 (i.e. not for entries like {S:[NP,VP]}